# Set Hyperlink into iReport

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports, ireport

I used `Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.1.0` in `ubntu 12.04`

I want create **Hyperlink**.

Two Report :- Report 1
              Report 2

In Report 1 set Hyperlink To called Report 2

Step :-

```
      Take on text element ex : ${ID}

      Right Click Hyperlink 

      Target : self       type : Report Execution

      Link Parameter :-    _report         "/path Report2"
```

In Preview Click Id than nothing happen and Report 2 not called

And Following Error Occurred:-

> Compiling to file... /home/mansi/Tweet_Report/report5.jasper
>   Compilation running time: 174!
>
> Filling report...
>
> Locale: English (India)   Time zone: Default Report fill running
>   time: 44! (pages generated: 1)    Exporting Text (iReport) to file...
>   /home/abc/R1_Report/Report1.txt!
>
> Error exporting print... net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintText.getTextAlignment()B
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintText.getTextAlignment()B
>
> at com.jaspersoft.jrx.export.JRTxtExporter.layoutGrid(JRTxtExporter.java:419)
>       at com.jaspersoft.jrx.export.JRTxtExporter.exportPage(JRTxtExporter.java:300)
>       at com.jaspersoft.jrx.export.JRTxtExporter.exportReportToWriter(JRTxtExporter.java:289)
>       at com.jaspersoft.jrx.export.JRTxtExporter.exportReport(JRTxtExporter.java:257)
>       at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:1174)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
>
> Export running time: 9!  No external viewer specified for this type of
>   print. Set it in the options frame!

Please help me to solved this Error.

Comment: Does report 2 run OK by itself?

Comment: yes...report 2 run OK

Comment: Does this error occur in iReport?

Comment: yes this error occur in iReport

Comment: Do you get the same error when you generate the report outside of iReport? For example, in JasperReports Server or another interface?

Comment: Try uploading the file to the server and see if you still have this problem. My hyperlinks only work on the server, not in iReport.

Answer (score 0):

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/803963/outputing-txt-file

It looks like you have to set the character height and width. From the page I have linked to:

> Go to Tools-->Options
>
> Select Export Options tab --> Select Text from left pane
>
> Set values for Character Width, Character Height, (The values I have set 7 and 13.9) Page width and Height.
>
> Now try generating the report and it will work. Try setting different values to make it fit properly.

Comment: I also set different hight and width for both page and character but still same error occurred.